# Объединить строки в разных файлах при условии их совпадения

Tags: linux, bash

Есть текстовый файл следующего вида:
file1

```
'alex';
'andrii';
'roman';
'anton.pe';
'nikolai';
```

file2

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'alex';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'andrii';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'roman';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'anton';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'nikolai';
```

Задача объединить эти данные вместе, условно если в строке с file2 есть значение с file1  то к значению с file1 в конец строки записать поле с file2, что бы получилось что-то подобное.

```
'alex'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'alex';
```

Я пробовал использовать команду read, но так и не мог написать условие для обработки данных.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [] then
        
    fi
done < 1.tx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то тк, возможно:

```
File=./f1.txt

while read line1
do
    cat f2.txt | while read line2
    do
        if [[ $line2 == *"$line1"* ]];
        then
            echo "$line1 $line2"
        fi
    done

done < $File
```

Запуская этот скрипт получим:

```
$ bash script.sh 
'alex'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'alex';
'andrii'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'andrii';
'roman'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'roman';
'nikolai'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'nikolai';
$
```

Comment: Ох, а если в файлах будет по n*10^3 строк, вы представляете, сколько времени это займет? Быстрее всего (если структура именно такая, как в вопросе), это сделать "ассоциативный массив\объект" ключом последнее  слово запроса, значением- сам запрос. А потом один раз пройтись по первому массиву и запрашивать запрос по ключу в новосозданном. Ну и, если есть, записывать\выводить.

Comment: @Zombotron - "Быстрее всего это сделать..." - Ну так сделайте! :-)

Comment: Понадобится, сделаю. )
Сейчас нима где затестить, а псеввдокод или вообще кривой выкладывать нет смысла.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, ваш вариант для меня вполне подходит. Это сэкономило мне кучу времини.

Answer (score 1):

к примеру, так:

```
$ join -2 7 -o "1.1 $(echo 2.{1..7})" <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

результат выполнения на основе приведённого в вопросе содержимого файлов:

```
'alex'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'alex';
'andrii'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'andrii';
'nikolai'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'nikolai';
'roman'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `base1`.* TO 'roman';
```

здесь:

- `join опции первый.файл второй.файл` — собственно объединение строк из двух файлов;
- `-2 7` — из второго файла отбирать только седьмое поле (по умолчанию разделитель полей — пробел);
- `-o формат` — выводить результат в требующемся формате. например: `1.2` — из первого файла вывести второе поле;
- `"1.1 $(echo 2.{1..7})"` — оболочкой преобразовывается в строку `"1.1 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7"`. как формат означает: взять из первого файла первое поле, из второго взять первое, второе, ... и седьмое;
- `программа <(команда)` — передача программе файлового дескриптора, в который записывается результат выполнения команды.